# IK bone and foot distortion

Tags: mesh, bones

Using a downloaded mesh I have watched tutorials and made notes on rigging and have got some of it working. The foot is not working properly and I'm getting confused trying to mend it. Is it possible to upload the blend file and get someone to point me in the right direction? I have actually uploaded a file called myman using pasteall.org but I've no idea where it is!

EDIT: I think the file may be at http://pasteall.org/blend/33002. Checked, it is.

EDIT2: When I move the heel IK bone the leg and foot move OK. Except that a part of the foot extrudes itself towards the world origin! Also if I move the heel too far the foot comes away from the leg! I seem to have got the hand right and I can't find a way to compare my good bone configurations with my bad ones.

Comment: It's not possible to find a file on pasteall by name. Upload it again, and record the URL of the page that shows after the upload is complete. You can provide that URL as a link to get the blend file.